# Excel keep fixed filter range

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

I know how to add filters in Excel, however for some reason when I choose a specific range and add a filter excel decides its going to extend my initial range.

In order to inform users there is an active filter I have the last row of data that reads "FILTER ACTIVER" and I select all data to the row **above** this, meaning when people add a filter they can clearly see the bottom row telling them they have a filter somewhere. (I know for most is clear when you have a filter, but sadly I have users that dont).

```
        A                  B
1    Human?              Color
2      Y                 Red
3      Y                 Green
4      N                 Yellow
5      Y                 Red
6                                           `last line of filter range
7  FILTER ACTIVE         FILTER ACTIVE
```

So if I choose range `A1:B6` and choose filter, I can filter by Y or N, or by colour just fine.

```
        A                  B
1    Human?              Color
2      Y                 Red
3      Y                 Green
5      Y                 Red
7  FILTER ACTIVE         FILTER ACTIVE
```

Once I clear that filter excel decides to extend the filtered range to be `A1:A7` and suddenly my last line is inclusive of the filter.

Is there a way to prevent this action?

Comment: Leave an extra blank row between the range you select and your "Filter Active" warning line?

Comment: Does the trick! Was hoping there was an excel option I had missed like "auto complete filter range" I could disable or something, but this will work thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Leave an extra blank line between your filter range and your "Filter Active" status notice.

With both tables and Filters, Excel will auto-expand to incorporate new data touching the edges.  This is often a useful feature.  In your cases like yours it isn't, but it can be prevented by leaving an extra blank row/column.

Comment: That is both disappointing and stupid.

Answer (score -1):

And when I preselect exactly the cells I want to filter, Excel decides that it knows better than I do, and expands the range. Microsoft: Please stop thinking you know what I want better than I do.

Comment: This is over 4 years old thread with an accepted answer. This isn't [an answer](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-answer) at all, just a rant against Microsoft. I'd suggest removing it.